# In Snowflake can I list all databases and their sizes?

Tags: snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I list all database along with the size in Snowflake.

The closest I can see is from this Snowflake document
[DATABASE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/database_storage_usage_history.html)

```
select *
from table(information_schema.database_storage_usage_history(dateadd('days',-10,current_date()),current_date()));
```

All I want is a list like this

**DatabaseName  Size(GB)**

MyDB1            10.5

HisDB2           21.3

HerDB3           17.8

Thanks,

Pete

Answer (score 1):

Using [DATABASE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/database_storage_usage_history.html#database-storage-usage-history-view):

> **This Account Usage view** can be used to query the average daily storage usage, in bytes, **for databases in the account** for the last 365 days (1 year). The data includes:

```
SELECT *
FROM snowflake.account_usage.DATABASE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY;
```

---

Related: [Differences Between Account Usage and Information Schema](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#differences-between-account-usage-and-information-schema)

Answer (score 0):

This will be up to 3 hours late, since it's shared back from Snowflake as a data share. There are other ways to get the information, but for current state, the TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS provides more information on time travel, failsafe, etc.

```
select      DATABASE_NAME
           ,sum(ACTIVE_BYTES / 1000000000) ACTIVE_GB
           ,sum(TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES / 1000000000) TIME_TRAVEL_GB
           ,sum(FAILSAFE_BYTES / 1000000000) FAILSAFE_GB
           ,sum(RETAINED_FOR_CLONE_BYTES / 1000000000) RETAINED_FOR_CLONE_GB
           ,ACTIVE_GB+TIME_TRAVEL_GB+FAILSAFE_GB+RETAINED_FOR_CLONE_GB TOTAL_GB
from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.DATABASES D
    left join SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS T
        on D.DATABASE_ID  = T.TABLE_CATALOG_ID
where   D.DELETED is null
group by DATABASE_NAME
order by DATABASE_NAME 
;
```